# How can I centrally manage filesystem redirection without cluttering my filesystem?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

When it comes to file organization, I run a tight ship, and many applications simply don't follow the rules of Windows (be it games saving to My Documents rather than %USERPROFILE%\Save Games, older games saving to their installation folders, cross-platform applications dumping their settings into %USERPROFILE% rather than %APPDATA%, and so forth).

For years now, I've been leveraging symlinks to make everything go where it should, but because most backup software traverses symlinks rather than saving them, I need to add ignore entries for each one to avoid file duplication, and with so many of them in so many different folders, restoring my symlinks after a format can be a nightmare.

As such, I'm wondering if there's an application out there, perhaps in the form of a filesystem driver, that will allow me to centrally manage my redirects **without cluttering my filesystem with symlinks**. If I create a rule to send "%USERPROFILE%\My App" to %APPDATA%, for example, all future access to "My App" by any program would be transparently redirected to %APPDATA%, and "%USERPROFILE%\My App" need not exist at all.

Does such a piece of software exist?